# Convert SVG circle to path with specific number of points?

Tags: svg, anime.js

I have two SVGs I want to morph between with Anime.Js, however they need to be the same number of points. So I either need a way to add points to an SVG or a way to convert a circle into a path with a specific number of points.

Here are the SVGs in question:

```
<svg id="svg1" width="290" height="290" viewBox="0 0 290 290" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M10,145a135,135 0 1,0 270,0a135,135 0 1,0 -270,0" />
</svg>
```

```
<svg width="290" height="290" viewBox="0 0 290 290" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M280 145C280 225.081 219.558 290 145 290C10 290 10 225.081 10 145C10 64.9187 70.4416 0 145 0C280 0 280 64.9187 280 145Z" />
</svg>
```

My assumption is that I might be able to just add points anywhere on the line of the circle's path in something like Figma. If that's the case, it's 22 points I need, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these values:

```
    var morphing = anime({
  targets: 'path',
  d: [
    { value: 'M 280 145C 280 219.5 205.5 280 145 280C 70.5 280 10 219.5 10 145C 10 70.5 70.5 10 145 10C 219.5 10 280 70.5 280 145Z' },
    { value: 'M 280 145C 280 225.081 219.558 290 145 290C 10 290 10 225.081 10 145C 10 64.9187 70.4416 0 145 0C 280 0 280 64.9187 280 145Z' }
  ],
  easing: 'easeOutQuad',
  duration: 10000,
  loop: true
});
```

It seems to work but I'm unfamiliar with the layout.
I tried substituting code into codepen [Anime.js Morphing Paths](https://codepen.io/inteo/pen/RMjYwV).
You can see the last two points of both svg data is identical and that's how I think it should be. And obviously creating a circle with cubic beziers as this also translates near to the squished circle / square. I've formatted the string exactly as it is in their example, didn't seem to work otherwise.